# FileNotFoundException and invalid input in varying runs

Tags: java

I'm new to coding. I'm currently trying to get an input value and grab information from a csv file and format it into a song method (predefined) via four outputs. However, I'm not able to get to this point because every time I try to run it through it saids it is unable to load it. Either that or it automatally cuts to the default in the switch statement, which I don't understand. I'm completely lost right now.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
/**
 * @author chasestauts
 *
 */
public class JukeboxHero {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        final String MENU = "*****************************"  + "\n" + "*      Program Menu         *" + "\n" + "*****************************"
                + "\n" + "(L)oad catalog" + "\n" + "(S)earch catalog" + "\n" + "(A)nalyse catalog" + "\n" + "(P)rint catalog" + "\n" + "(Q)uit"
                + "\n" + "\n";
        final String cR = ("Please enter a command (press 'm' for Menu):");

        System.out.print(MENU + cR);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String decision = input.nextLine();

        while(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("q") == false)
        {
            System.out.println(cR);
            decision = input.nextLine();
            switch (decision){
            case ("L"):
            {
                ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
                System.out.println("Load Catalog..");
                System.out.print("Please enter filename: ");
                String filepath = input.nextLine();
                File songFile = new File(filepath);
                try 
                {
                    Scanner songScan = new Scanner(songFile);
                    while (songScan.hasNext())
                    {
                        String line  = songScan.nextLine();
                        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
                        lineScan.useDelimiter(",");
                        while (lineScan.hasNext())
                        {
                            String artist = lineScan.next();
                            String album = lineScan.next();
                            String title = lineScan.next();
                            int duration = lineScan.nextInt();
                            Song song = new Song(title, artist, album, duration);
                            songList.add(song);
                        }
                        lineScan.close();
                    }
                    songScan.close();
                    int size = songList.size() + 1;
                    System.out.println("Successfully loaded " + size + " songs!");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException error)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, unable to open file: " + filepath);
                }
            }
            break;
            case ("S"):
            {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
            case ("A"):
            {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
            case ("P"):
            {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
            case ("Q"):
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
            }
            case ("M"):
            {
                System.out.println(MENU);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            }
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Did you check the value of `decision`? Could it contain whitespace characters, lower case chars etc.? That comment "used from stackoverflow the case, case thing" indicates you're not familiar with the switch-case construct, is that correct?

Comment: Could you specify the filepath given as the input?

I used this path its working for me.

File songFile = new File("C:\\stackoverflow\\parseFile.csv");

Comment: Can you add some snippets of the output, I can't understand your explanation

Comment: Where is the file in your system? You should give absolute path to the file you are reading. You should give path as "C:\pathfolder\filename.csv" or in linux /usr/pathfolder/filename.cs, in order to read the file without exception.

Comment: *****************************
*      Program Menu         *
*****************************
(L)oad catalog
(S)earch catalog
(A)nalyse catalog
(P)rint catalog
(Q)uit

Please enter a command (press 'm' for Menu):L
Please enter a command (press 'm' for Menu):
L
Load Catalog..
Please enter filename: music-collection.csv
Sorry, unable to open file: music-collection.csv
Please enter a command (press 'm' for Menu):
L
Load Catalog..
Please enter filename: music-collection.csv
Sorry, unable to open file: music-collection.csv
Please enter a command (press 'm' for Menu):
l

Comment: Found the issue, since I'm using an IDE, the files that I was calling were inside of my src folder. Which led to me being inable to access them.